# Group By Statuses using reduce

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been using `reduce()` method to group by Open and Closes statuses (`Status_111`, `Status_222`, etc) which then creates an array of which Ids (`item.Id`) it is associated with.

Code is working and with an expected result but how do I avoid duplicated check when somewhat it does a similar thing and create blank arrays (Open and Close Status can have same Id (eg: `Status_111`), I am referring to this block section:

```
if (item.Open && !obj[item.Open]) {
    obj[item.Open] = {
      Open: [],
      Close: []
    }
}

if (item.Close && !obj[item.Close]) {
  obj[item.Close] = {
    Open: [],
    Close: []
  }
}
```

Usage:

```js
const items = [
  { Id: 100, Open: 'Status_111', Close: 'Status_111' },
  { Id: 200, Open: 'Status_111', Close: 'Status_222' },
  { Id: 300, Open: 'Status_333', Close: 'Status_444' }
]

function groupByOpenAndClose(items) {
  return items.reduce(function (obj, item) {
    if (item.Open && !obj[item.Open]) {
        obj[item.Open] = {
          Open: [],
          Close: []
        }
    }

    if (item.Close && !obj[item.Close]) {
      obj[item.Close] = {
        Open: [],
        Close: []
      }
    }

    if (obj[item.Open]) {
      obj[item.Open].Open.push(item.Id)
    }

    if (obj[item.Close]) {
      obj[item.Close].Close.push(item.Id)
    }

    return obj
  }, {});
}

console.log(groupByOpenAndClose(items));
```

Comment: Perhaps posting this question at codereview is more suitable.

Comment: And here is the link: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `reduce` with a `forEach` is one way to get there

```js
const items = [{
    Id: 100,
    Open: 'Status_111',
    Close: 'Status_111'
  },
  {
    Id: 200,
    Open: 'Status_111',
    Close: 'Status_222'
  },
  {
    Id: 300,
    Open: 'Status_333',
    Close: 'Status_444'
  }
]

let status = items.reduce((b, a) => {
  ['Open', 'Close'].forEach(s => {
    b[a[s]] = b[a[s]] || {Open: [], Close: []}
  });
  return b
}, {});

items.forEach(s => {
  status[s.Open].Open.push(s.Id);
  status[s.Close].Close.push(s.Id)
});

console.log(status)
```

Comment: I think you can have `b[a.Open].Open.push(a.Id);` inside reduce method after forEach.

Comment: I initially tried that but there was the case where I would want to maybe insert a value into a `Status_xxxxx` that had not yet been created